How can I format a text passed via props (adding span, strong...) in NextJs
I'm trying to find the best way to add some html (strong, span) and css styling via props.
So my component could be reusable with different input and I could format it directly via the props.
I want the words with $* *$ to be rendered in strong tag but I'm afraid about injections
<HeroCourse title="La $*grammaire*$ de l’espagnol"
description="Toutes les $**règles**$ de grammaire pour apprendre à lire, écrire et parler espagnol" 
/>

I have this code but I know it's not the right way.
import Input from './../UI/buttons/Input'; 
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import styles from "./HeroCourse.module.css";

function parseCustomSyntax(text) {
  // Replace occurrences of *text* with <span style="color: red;">text</span>
  text = text.replace(/\*([^*]*)\*/g, '<span style="color: red;">$1</span>');

  // Replace occurrences of **text** with <strong>text</strong>
  text = text.replace(/\*\*([^*]*)\*\*/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');

  // Replace occurrences of $*text*$ with <strong style="color: red;">text</strong>
  text = text.replace(/\$\*([^$]*)\*\$/g, '<strong style="color: red;">$1</strong>');

  // Replace occurrences of $**text**$ with <span>$1</span>
  text = text.replace(/\$\*\*([^$]*)\*\*\$/g, '<span>$1</span>');

  return text;
}

function HeroCourse({ title, description, inputProps }) {
  const formattedTitle = parseCustomSyntax(title);
  const formattedDescription = parseCustomSyntax(description);

  return (
    <div className={styles["hero-course-container"]}>
      <div className={styles["hero-course"]}>
        <h2 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(formattedTitle) }} />
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(formattedDescription) }} />
        <Input {...inputProps} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeroCourse;

Thank you everyone for helping me !

Given that you're using DOMPurify, injections should already be prevented so this approach seems correct.

Ok thank you so this should be the nornmal way to format my text via props by adding span and strong. I will create an export function to do it so. If you have a better way or a library, could you tell me please.  Thank you !
